# Saving the output of a child process in a variable in the parent in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, parent-child, ipc, child-process

I would like to start a child process in NodeJS and save it's output into a variable. The following code gives it to stdout:

```
require("child_process").execSync("echo Hello World", {"stdio": "inherit"});
```

I have something in mind that is similar to this code:

```
var test;
require("child_process").execSync("echo Hello World", {"stdio": "test"});
console.log(test);
```

The value of `test` was supposed to be `Hello World`.

Which does not work, since `"test"` is not a valid stdio value.

Perhaps this is possible using environment variables, however I did not find out how to modify them in the child process with the result still being visible to the parent.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[`execSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execsync_command_options) is a function which *returns* the stdout of the command you pass in, so you can store its output into a variable with the following code:

```
var child_process = require("child_process");
var test = child_process.execSync("echo Hello World");
console.log(test);
// => "Hello World"
```

Be aware that this will throw an error if the exit code of the process is non-zero. Also, note that you may need to use `test.toString()` as `child_process.execSync` can return a `Buffer`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I would like to add that I had to use `test.toString()`, otherwise the output was `<Buffer 48 65 6c 6c 6f 20 57 6f 72 6c 64 0a>`.

Comment: @pfo will note this - I think it varies with the version since my local copy didn't do that.

Comment: How do you do that if it exists with a non-zero exit code though?